# canvas arc function flicker when set shadow and gradient in safari

Tags: javascript, html, css, canvas

When I redraw the arc, the canvas will flicker in safari. But when I remove shadow or gradient, it works fine.
Here is the code.

```js
var ctx = document.querySelector('canvas').getContext('2d');
var angle = 0;
setInterval(function () {
    if (++angle > 360) {
        angle = 1;
    }
    draw(angle);
}, 30);

function draw(angle) {
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 200, 200);
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.lineWidth = 3;

    // shadow
    ctx.shadowBlur = 20;
    ctx.shadowColor = 'yellow';
    ctx.shadowOffsetX = 0;
    ctx.shadowOffsetY = 0;

    // gradient
    var grd = ctx.createLinearGradient(100, 0, 100, 100);
    grd.addColorStop(0, 'red');
    grd.addColorStop(1, 'blue');
    ctx.strokeStyle = grd;

    ctx.arc(100, 100, 80, 0, Math.PI / 180 * angle);
    ctx.stroke();
    ctx.closePath();
}
```

```html
<canvas width="200" height="200"></canvas>
```

Here is my safari version

```
Mac
Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_13_6) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/11.1.2 Safari/605.1.15"

iPhone
Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 11_4 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/11.0 Mobile/15E148 Safari/604.1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A long bug. You can overcome it by first drawing a shadow without a gradient, and on top is a gradient without a shadow:

```js
var ctx = document.querySelector('canvas').getContext('2d');
var angle = 0;
setInterval(function () {
    if (++angle > 360) {
        angle = 1;
    }
    draw(angle);
}, 30);

function draw(angle) {
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 200, 200);
    ctx.lineWidth = 3;

    // shadow without a gradient
    ctx.strokeStyle = 'yellow';
    ctx.shadowBlur = 20;
    ctx.shadowColor = 'yellow';
    ctx.shadowOffsetX = 0;
    ctx.shadowOffsetY = 0;
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(100, 100, 80, 0, Math.PI / 180 * angle);
    ctx.stroke();
    ctx.closePath();

    // gradient without a shadow
    ctx.shadowBlur = 0;
    var grd = ctx.createLinearGradient(100, 0, 100, 100);
    grd.addColorStop(0, 'red');
    grd.addColorStop(1, 'blue');
    ctx.strokeStyle = grd;
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(100, 100, 80, 0, Math.PI / 180 * angle);
    ctx.stroke();
    ctx.closePath();
}
```

```html
<canvas width="200" height="200"></canvas>
```